# How do you indent your HTML?

Tags: php, html, indentation

Given the HTML generated by my application.

```
function pagination(){
  echo "<ul>\n";

  for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    echo "\t<li>...</li>\n";

  echo "</ul>\n";
}
?>
<div>
  <?php pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

If I add another container DIV, this doesn't produce correctly indented code.

Is there any solution for the function to somehow know how many \t 's or spaces to add, or somehow automatically indent the html?

Comment: If this is output for your actual page, you *shouldn't* indent it. That's just more characters the user has to download. Firebug and other structure debugging tools will automatically do that for you when you inspect elements.

Comment: If you were to have sections as loaded views like a mvc pattern this would not be too bad as the views html would most likely be on first indent. also its prefered to use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` or `\r\n` then new lines are compat with all systems.

Comment: @Lawrence your MVC pater has absolutely nothing to do with this question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Amazing question.

9 answers and 3 comments so far, and looks like nobody bothered to read the question body, but just repeated some gospel triggered by a keyword in the title - a most preferred manner to answer questions on the blessed site of stackoverflow.

Yet the question not that simple/one-layered.
I have to admit, it's ambiguous itself. So, we have to dig it out.

> 1) How do you indent your HTML?

Use templates, dude. Use templates. The only answer.

> 2) Is there any solution for the function to somehow know how many \t 's or spaces to add, or somehow automatically indent the html?

**Of course there isn't**.
PHP knows nothing of HTML, indents and such.
*Especially when no HTML is ready yet(!)*

> 3) If I add another container DIV, this doesn't produce correctly indented code.

The **key** question of the question.
The question for sake of which the question were asked.

Yet hardest of them all.

And the answer is kind of ones I showed total disagreement with, hehe:
Although relative order of tags is important, for the resulting large HTML it is possible to move some blocks out of row:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div>
<!-- news list -->
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1..</li>
    <li>2..</li>
    <li>3..</li>
    <li>4..</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /news list -->
    </div>
    <div>
<!-- pagination -->
<ul>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Green</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Black</li>
</ul>
<!-- /pagination -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It will let you have proper indention in the meaningful blocks, yet keep the main HTML in order.
As a side effect it will keep your lines on the screen :)

To keep good indentation inside sub-templates, I'd strongly suggest using PHP-based templates. Not ugly HEREDOC for goodness' sake!
Here is only one rule to follow with PHP templates:
**always keep PHP blocks to the left side.** That's all.
To keep indentation between PHP nested blocks, just indent them inside `<? ?>`

Example:

```
<ul>
<? foreach ($thelist as $color): ?>
  <li>
<?   if ($color == $current): ?>
    <b><?=$color?></b>
<?   else ?>
    <a href="?color=<?=$color?>"><?=$color?></a>
<?   endif ?>
  </li>
<? endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

This will produce correctly indented HTML, while keeping order of both HTML and PHP in the template, making developer's life easer both at development and *debugging*.

Do not listen to anyone who says "no need to indent your code at all!". They are merely hobbyists, not the real developers. Anyone who have an idea of what *debugging* is, who had hard times debugging their code, would tell you that proper indentation is essential.

Comment: I do use templates, but there are situations (like the pagination thing) where using templates is kind of stupid, because you have to do complicated stuff inside your template. See for example [this class](https://github.com/onassar/PHP-Pagination), which is basically useless, the render.inc does all the job that goes in the template...

Comment: You just taking templates wrong. Templates are definitely not to make things "simple" (not complicated). Templates are to separate data processing from data displaying. They can be comlicated as well but they have to be separated from the data processing. Any class mixing these matters is a rubbish. The point of my post was quite different though.

Comment: "Anyone who have an idea of what debugging is, who had hard times debugging their code, would tell you that proper indentation is essential." <- That's simply no longer true. There are several implementations of "View Source" that allow you to (re-)indent the code client-side. For this reason I now allow Railo to collapse all excess whitespace which reduces the amount of bytes to be sent.

Comment: @SpliFF all these implementations do *render* the code. This or that way they alter it. Some DOM changes, even attempts to correct wrong tags - the purpose of these viewers is different from debugging output - that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The answer could sound weird, but you should not worry about the generated code's indentation. Indentation is for readability, and should be only of concern on the programmer's side, not on the generated part (which is for browsers).

Comment: Where I generally agree. I do often find it nice to have some pretty source. For the snoops that is. still +1 because it's the most sensible response.

Comment: That's true. usual PHP user have no idea of HTML generated by their script and don't care.

Comment: I didn't but I want to -1. It doesn't answer the question at all. The OP wants to know how to indent generated HTML. Instead everyone keeps answering "You shouldn't" or "No Point". Well there is a point, that's what the OP wants. As for "formatted code is only for developers" how about a client looking at the source of there website, so see unreadable code? Not very professional.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all comments saying don't bother but if you do have a case where doing so makes sense then you can pipe your HTML through [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net) (or in your case [PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)) using the `indent` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you add **\t** in front of ul you should be able to see the code prettied up

```
<?php
function pagination(){
  echo "\t<ul>\n";

  for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    echo "\t\t<li>...</li>\n";

  echo "\t</ul>\n";
}
?>
<div>
<?php pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: the question was how to add *variable* number of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Most editors have some sort of formatting function which can be used to fix indentation. In Visual Studio for example you can hit Ctrl + K + D to nicely format your html.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it something like this if it's a more complicated html structure. This makes it easier to follow if you ask me, and you also can write your html normally instead of worrying about escaping quotes and things like that.

Since you're not in a PHP block when it's processing the HTML, it will come out as indented as you make it.

```
<?php
function pagination(){
echo "</ul>\n";
   for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
   {
?>
        <li>...</li>
<?php
   }

echo "</ul>\n";
}
?>
<div>
   <?php pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;

/* More complex example, with variables. */
class foo
{
    var $foo;
    var $bar;

    function foo()
    {
        $this->foo = 'Foo';
        $this->bar = array('Bar1', 'Bar2', 'Bar3');
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
$name = 'MyName';

echo <<<EOT
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
    Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
    This should print a capital 'A': \x41
    Notice all of the indenting is preserved.
EOT;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, he could. But what does it do with the question?

Comment: `or somehow automatically indent the html?` this would be one of those ways... s/automatically/preserve

Comment: in his own current solution indents are preserved already. Not preservation he is looking for. Not to mention that with ugly heredoc no html color highlighting, auto-completion and such things could be possible.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel his question was vague, and I contributed the best solution to the problem I interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, **use templates**.

If you properly separate your logic from your presentation, this question goes away.  Your **templates** will have all the indenting or lack of indenting you want or need.

**EDIT**

Nonetheless, you can modify your code pretty simply:

```
<?php
function pagination($depth=0) {
  $indent = str_pad("", $depth, "\t");
  echo $indent."<ul>\n";

  for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    echo $indent."\t<li>...</li>\n";

  echo $indent."</ul>\n";
}
?>
<div>
  <?php pagination(1); ?>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <?php pagination(2); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively,  you can just pass in the indent you want:

```
<?php
function pagination($indent="") {
  echo $indent."<ul>\n";

  for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    echo $indent."\t<li>...</li>\n";

  echo $indent."</ul>\n";
}
?>
<div>
  <?php pagination("\t"); ?>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <?php pagination("\t\t"); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question was how to add a helper block into template, keeping overall indentation. Ever heard of template helper functions?

Comment: The question is vague at best and says nothing of templates or helper blocks.

Comment: The **function** in the opening post IS such a helper. Used to output the same HTML block in the **different** templates for sake of not duplicating the code.

Comment: Well, now it's at least the answer to the question were asked.

Answer (score 0):

I am a stickler for well formed code as well. Alot of people here said "firebug will indent your code for you". Well, what about when the markup delivered to the browser is modified through or injected into the DOM via javascript? Then firebug shows you the current state, not what you loaded from the server.

I also like my html to be visible and readable throughout my script. I generally do something like this, keeping track of PHP and HTML indentation separately (it is not to be able to put your cursor on an opening tag or `{` and just scroll the page down until you find the closing tag or `}` conveniently lined up with your cursors position.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div><?php
$thelist = array('Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Black');
echo '
        <ul>';
foreach ($thelist as $color) {
    echo '
            <li>' . $color . '</li>';
}
echo '
        </ul>';
?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This outputs just like so,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Green</li>
            <li>Blue</li>
            <li>Black</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice is looks just like it should, and like it does in the script (this makes debugging simple for me). I use single quotes with HTML so I do not have to escape a trillion quotes (this makes concatenating strings a bit more manual but it is less work than all those back slashes; which also hinder readability within the script).

Once again, this is just how I do things and may not be the ideal way to handle formatting HTML. I just like to have my HTML nice and neat even when its mixed with PHP

Comment: this probably produces nice output but it is support-nightmare non-templating approach at all. And, frankly, the code is just ugly.

Comment: I agree with @YourCommonSense, but wouldn't `echo '....<li>' . $color . '</li>' . "\n";` make your code a lot more readable? or even `echo "....<li>$color</li>\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: broke the code down into pages.

This code really only works with a template system.
Which can just be a basic:

```
// file: index.tpl.html

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Some header code</div>
        <div>
            {mainContent}
        </div>
        <div>Some footer code</div>
    </body>
</html>

// file: functions.php
<?php
    function pagination()
    {
        $output = "<ul>\n";

        for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
            $output = "\t<li>...</li>\n";

        $output = "</ul>\n";

        return $output;
    }

    function indent_html($html, $tag, $new_html)
    {
        // magic indenting code: finds how many spaces are used on the line above it
        $spacePos = 0;
        $find  = strpos($html, '{'.$tag.'}' );
        while( $html[ $find-$spacePos-1] == ' ' ) $spacePos++;

        // Uses the indent from the line above to indent your new html
        return str_replace("\n", "\n".str_repeat(" ", $spacePos), $new_html);
    }
?>

// file: index.php
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents("index.tpl.html");

    // magic indenting code: finds how many spaces are used on the line above it
    $spacePos = 0;
    $find  = strpos($html, '{mainContent}' );
    while( $html[ $find-$spacePos-1] == ' ' ) $spacePos++;

    // your pagination() needs to return html not output it
    $mainContent = pagination();
    $mainContent = indent_html($html, $tag, $mainContent);

    // Uses the indent from the line above to indent your new html
    $mainContent = str_replace("\n", "\n".str_repeat(" ", $spacePos), $mainContent);

    // finally insert your html
    $html = str_replace("{mainContent}", $mainContent, $html);
?>
```

Might need some modification if you want to use tabs instead of spaces.
I use spaces as it's more cross browser/application.

Comment: what is the "template system" you are talking about?

Comment: Why the down vote? It answers the question, all generated code gets indented. and @YourCommonSense I was just showing how it can be used, `home/index.tpl.html` would contain `{mainContent}` which gets replaced with the generated code, and indented to the same level as the code surrounding it.

Comment: your solution use no tamplates. so, it shouldn't be used at all

Comment: A template is just a reusable file. It doesn't have to be called from a 2000 line class to be called a "template system". The fact the html page doesn't have any dynamic (php in this case) code in it, is enough to call it a template.

Comment: You just have no idea what a template is and *what it is used for.* There is no problem in having a dynamic code in the template. (Moreover, it's just impossible to avoid it!) But **to use templates you shouldn't have any static HTML in your PHP code either**

Comment: I think I provided a nice lightweight example of a template system. my answer wasn't showing template functionality, but where my indent solution would be positioned in the code. But I've noticed you just seem to be argumentative. So I'll just put it down to that.

Comment: it is not a "lightweight" template. Your terrific `$output = "\t<li>...</li>\n";` is NOT A TEMPLATE AT ALL. Go figure.

Comment: yeah no shit, the function pagination() is from the question. index.tpl.html is the template. Don't comment on code that isn't mine.

Comment: it is yours. you are not using a template in your answer. so, your answer is just useless.

Comment: Well I am, I said that in my last comment, index.tpl.html is the template. And my index.php processes all the data and places it into index.tpl.html. Which makes it a template system. an no, if you look at the question, pagination() is the majority of the question, you can't miss it. Maybe you should go back to basics? Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template

Comment: A silly html page doesn't make a template system, lol. One can say that they have a template system ONLY if they have their business logic FULLY separated from the presentation logic. While your index.php does process the data as well as design, mixing it and thus spoiling whole idea of templates. think of it. The page you linked to says plain nonsense. you cannot separate your content from design.

Comment: A template doesn't have anything to do with business logic. You can quite simply use php in it's basic form, and use $head_title $body_content to reuse a block of html (in this case index.tpl.html
) with no further logic than including aboutus.html, services.html which has the actual content. You talking about mixing data and design is getting into things like design patterns (like the all popular MVC). When talking about templates, it is literally a way not so have <html><head><title> copied onto every page that gets called.

Comment: How about elaborating your idea of a template (if it's not a html file) instead of constantly telling me I'm wrong? That would be a lot more constructive.